# Creating default set of username/password from a csv file in a web2py application

Tags: python, web2py

Basically, I would like to deploy a web2py application with a set of default users already registered/created in the application.

Can this be accomplished by importing a CSV file containing default username/password and other details into the auth_user table?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It can be accomplished this way.
Welcome to SO, by the way. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how questions should be asked around here. Then, please provide some insights what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please read the relevant [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Exporting-and-importing-data) and come back with a more specific question after you try what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually, just:

- go to your application admin interface
- click on the "database admin" button (mighy be translated to your OS language)
- click on db.auth_user
- then use the Import/Export feature form at the bottom of the page

That's it.